# Why doesn't the color of an object change when signal of different frequency impinge upon it?

Tags: visible-light, spectroscopy

Correct me if I'm wrong but I've always thought that the color that an object has is due to the oscillation of the atoms that makes up the material of that object. When white light is shine upon an object, the atoms oscillates at a certain frequency and reflects color in the form of EM radiation.

In this case, why wouldn't the color of an object change if a light source of significantly higher frequency impinge upon this object making the atoms oscillate at different frequency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apparent color of an object *does* change when different frequencies of light are incident.  In the extreme case that light of a single frequency is incident, only that frequency is reflected, and the color of the object ... and every object ... is the color of the incident light.

The apparent color of an object changes under different types of "white light", as well.  Our brains usually can correct for this and we don't notice it, but digital cameras don't, at least not as well.  Hence digital cameras have a "white balance" setting which shifts the colors of objects so that a white wall will appear white in the photo instead of yellow (if illuminated by incandescent light) or bluish (if illuminated by certain fluorescent lights).

Some combinations of dyes or pigments cause a significant change in apparent color depending  on the light source.  This is called [*metamerism*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamerism_%28color%29).  I have a vase that is a particular shade of blue under sunlight, and a strikingly different shade under incandescent light.

Comment: Hi do you have a link to a video perhaps showing this phenomenon?

Comment: You can Google as well as I.  I got 43,900 hits for "metatmerism video".     Doing your work for you, I found that in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sJP7X-NVAGQ) at 0:51, there is an example.

Answer (score 0):

The phenomenon is a little different that you describe. A red object, for instance, absorbs most of the frequecies and only reflects back the ones on the red spectrum. Actually the reason that a red object looks black on blue light (which has higher frequency) is that the blue light will be absorved by the object (not reemited), and there is no red light to be reflected. The result is that now the red object looks black.

Comment: 1. What happens to the absorbed energy? 2. What governs how much reflection occurs?

Comment: 1) it is reemited as heat 2) the molecular structure of the object, in that you are correct. However the band structure of the electrons forbides them from absorbing certain energies (it is a quantum mechanical phenomeon, not classical.